# Signing Configuration in gradle.build

Tags: google-play, gradle, apk, android-studio

I'm developing in Android Studio 0.2.11, and I'm trying to upload my app to Google Play. When I was trying to generate a signed APK (by clicking Build -> Generate Signed APK) I get the following message:

"For Gradle-based projects, the signing configuration should be specified in the Gradle build scripts. See the Gradle User Guide for more info".

I googled a lot, and found out that I need to add some functions into gradle.build, like `signingConfigs` and `buildTypes` with a `storeFile`, `storePassword`, `keyAlias` and `keyPassword`. This is all the code that I have in gradle.build at the moment:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "******"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

I don't know what alias, password and store type I'm supposed to write? Where do I find the right ones? And what is the next step? How do I get a signed APK so that I can upload it to Google Play?

Any help is very appreciated, I've been searching for a solution for hours now on the internet.

Comment: 0.2.13 reintroduced this feature. You can generate your keystore and sing with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There is Issue on [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60762) about your problem. Temporary solution:

> Configure your signing configurations as described in the user guide.
>   Then, run "gradle assembleRelease", and you will find your APK in the build/apk/ directory.

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks for your links but I'm still stuck!

Comment: Use Keytool and Jarsigner - [Signing in Release Mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode)

Comment: Am i suppose to write something in settings.gradle? Cause this doesn't work!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Here's [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations)